# POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/upload.php net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php

im trying to make a file upload page and im getting this problem
POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/upload.php net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)

**upload.js**

```
const mainform = document.getElementById('mainform');
const inpFile = document.getElementById('inpFile');


mainform.addEventListener('submit', e => {

    e.preventDefault();


    const endpoint = 'upload.php';

    const formData = new FormData();


    formData.append('inpFile', inpFile.files[0]);


    fetch(endpoint, {
        method:"POST",
        body: formData
    }).catch(console.error);
});
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

$targetPath = 'videos/' . basename($_FILES[inpFile]['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['inpFile']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
```

Comment: fyi, `$_FILES[inpFile]['name']` should be `$_FILES['inpFile']['name']`

Comment: @brombeer it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update JSON files in that way, but you can use a database or apply the same code with the help of node server(node.js)